# Cannot draw Diagram using Plot in R

Tags: r

```
 plot( table1$Petal.Length, table1$Petal.Width, type="l",  col="red" )
 plot( table1$Petal.Length, table1$Petal.Width, type="l",  col="Green" )

 par(new=TRUE)
 plot( table1$Petal.Length ~ table1$Sepal.Width,table1$Petal.Width, type="l",  
 col="Green" )
```

When i run above code i get he following error

```
  Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : numeric 'envir' arg not of length one
```

Comment: To get a quick and accurate answer, it can help to include a description or image of what you'd like the output to look like, along with sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because you are trying to plot three variables in a 2-dimensional plot. The third argument `table1$Petal.Width` for `plot` is invalid because `plot` only takes `x` and `y`. Also, `type="l"` makes a line plot which doesn't seem to make sense here. `type="p"` gives a scatterplot (the default):

```
table1=iris

plot( table1$Petal.Length ~ table1$Sepal.Width, type="p",  
      col="Blue" )
```

[image]

Furthermore, your `Petal.Length` in the first two `plot` are treated differently from the third because `Petal.Length` was treated as the `x` variable, and `Petal.Width` the `y` variable. The formula `table1$Petal.Length ~ table1$Sepal.Width` means "plot the left hand side variable (`y`) against the right hand side (`x`)". So `Petal.Length` in this case is the `y` variable.

There are ways to represent three variables in a single scatterplot, but it is a bit tricky if they are all continuous. One way would be to discretize the third variable by intervals and see how it varies in relation to the others. For example, the plot below is quite informative:

```
table1$Petal.Width_factor = cut(table1$Petal.Width, breaks = 4)

plot( Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, type="p",  
      col=Petal.Width_factor, data=table1 )

legend("topright", c(levels(table1$Petal.Width_factor)), 
       pch = 1, col = 1:4, title = "Petal Width")
```

[image]

Note that you can use the `data=table1` argument to specify your dataset so you don't have to type `table1$` for each variable.